# An 'opinionateduser' site?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, discussion

I have some questions about how other people handle things related to programming , but not programming questions per se. How they deal with a client issue etc.

If there were a site that was for asking those types of questions it would be helpful to others as well I am sure.

Lots of the poll, opinion, type things could be migrated there as well.

It does't seem wrong to want to specifically ask a large group of programmers how they handle non-programming issues. Is this the wrong place to ask for a feature like that?

Comment: We have one of these already. It's called **every forum on the Internet**. You may have heard of it.

Comment: I actually thought it might actually improve the other sites by removing opinion content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Can't find one? Make it happen.](https://stackexchange.com/)

If you build a compelling enough site, you'll be well on your way to building the community you're looking for.

What makes this site special is that all (well, most) of that opinionated stuff isn't here detracting away from what we came for: specific answers to specific programming questions. This site is better for being focused on a specific set of objectives.

Comment: this is probably right, but the volume of users already here with relevant experience would be hard to reproduce.